# php submit button disabled if want to edit data

Tags: php, jquery

i got a problem where , if i want to edit the data the submit button is disabled . by the way , the data already exist but we want to edit some field e.g : id_no etc (use autocomple script)
this is the function to validate the data .

```
function validate()
{
    if((\$('txt_no_kp').value != '') 
        && (\$('txt_nama').value != '') 
        && (\$('txt_alamat').value != ''))
    {
        \$('btn_basic').disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        \$('btn_basic').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

this is the form php

```
<td colspan="2">
    <strong>Name</strong>
    <div id="div_nama">
        <input name="txt_nama" type="text" id="txt_nama" onchange="validate()" size="40" />
    </div>
</td>
<td colspan="2">
    <strong>Alamat</strong><br />
    <div id="div_alamat">
        <textarea name="txt_alamat" id="txt_alamat" cols="40" rows="3" onchange="validate()"></textarea>
    </div>
</td>
```

here the button coding :

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_basic" id="btn_basic" value="Simpan" />
```

Comment: you need to selector before field get $('#txt_no_kp').value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code :

```
function validate()
{
    if(($('#txt_no_kp').value != '') 
        && ($('#txt_nama').value != '') 
        && ($('#txt_alamat').value != ''))
    {
        $('#btn_basic').prop('disabled',false);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#btn_basic').prop('disabled',true);
    }
}
```